# How to verify datatype in C# asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, types

I pass the custom data type of C# struct and now I want to get know which type it is in the attribute I put on them   in  `ActionFilterAttribute`.

How  can I check the type of viewdata.Model in ActionFilterAttribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filterContext.ParentActionViewContext.ViewData.Model.GetType();
```

This will give you type of the model

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling [GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx)() on the struct?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (filterContext.ParentActionViewContext.ViewData.Model is YourType) {
}
```